# Connecting to a SQL Server through another Sever connection that's not linked

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

So I am tasked with creating a query that uses data from two separate databases on two separate servers. I've been told that linking the servers will not be an option but there is a sql command that can be used to properly address the server I want to connect to.  Can anyone clue me in on what that command might be?

EX:

Server 01
Database_01
Table01

Server 02
Database_02
Table02

If I had a linked server I could simply do this.

```
SELECT s2.*, s1.somefield
FROM [Server 02].[Database_02].[Table02] s2
JOIN  [Server 01].[Database_01].[Table01] s1
on s2.id = s1.id
```

Since I don't have that option, I need to find another way to reference Server 02 if I am connected to Server 01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need either [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)
or [OPENDATASOURCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)

Found examples [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/working-example-of-opendatasource-command-using-sql-authentication):

OPENROWSET:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
   'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;UID=MyUserID;PWD=MyCleverPassword',
   'select @@ServerName')
```

OPENDATASOURCE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI', -- or SQLNCLI
   'Data Source=OtherServer\InstanceName;Catalog=RemoteDB;User ID=SQLLogin;Password=Secret;').RemoteDB.dbo.SomeTable
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking at these as the alternative.